# Event listener on select field in Symfony 1.4

Tags: select, symfony1, event-handling, listener

I got two select fields in my symfony project: ContrySelect and StateSelect. They are implemented with the sfDependentSelectPlugin. I just want to know if does it exist a way to listen to the events of the CountrySelect so I can set or unset the StateSelect field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I only worked once with this plugin.
It has an option for the sfWidgetFormDependentSelect which is called 'ajax'.
See doc:

> ajax = false: Specifies whether remote calls are used to populate the
>   select values,

This may be an option.

Otherwise I would advise you to just create a custom javascript listener on your CountrySelect that will set the other widget.